# WPF Overlay does not activate until after button has finished

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, caliburn.micro

I have a small sample WPF application using Caliburn Micro. In it, I have a rectangle overlay that says loading. I want this to appear whenever a large task is loading however it doesn't appear until after the method is finished. I have tried using Dispatch as well as other suggestions howver nothing works until after the button method is finished. Below is my current example

```
  public async void TheActionButton()
        {
            //Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new System.Action(() => { IsLoadingMessageVisible = true; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsLoadingMessageVisible); }));
            Execute.OnUIThread(new System.Action(() => { IsLoadingMessageVisible = true; NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsLoadingMessageVisible); }));
            await LongMethod();
        }
```

The overlay shows up only after LongMethod() is finished running. Is there a way to get it to show before the method runs?

Comment: How is `LongMethod` implemented? It's probably not asynchronous despite it's signature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted the implementation of `LongMethod` so it's impossible to say what it actually does, but I would guess that it isn't implemented as an asynchronous and blocks the UI thread.

You may try to execute it on a background thread using a `Task`:

```
public async void TheActionButton()
{
    IsLoadingMessageVisible = true;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsLoadingMessageVisible);
    await Task.Run(LongMethod);
}
```

A method isn't automatically asynchronous just because it returns a `Task` or a `Task<T>` and can be awaited.

Comment: It was the method... I need to re-write it to truly make it asynchronous. For now until I have time I can use `await Task.Run(async () => await Task.Delay(1));` til I have time to refactor. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You should use the TAP (Task-based Asynchronous Programming), it integrates well with such use cases.

```
async void TheActionButton() 
{
    IsLoadingMessageVisible = true;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsLoadingMessageVisible);

    await LongMethod();

    IsLoadingMessageVisible = false;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => IsLoadingMessageVisible);
}
```

**Note**: implement your `IsLoadingMessageVisible` in the way so that you don't need to call `NotifyOfPropertyChange()` each time you set the property.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I added the `NotifyofPropertyChange()` to the setter of the `IsLoadingMessageVisible`. Now the function is just `public async void TheActionButton()
        {
            IsLoadingMessageVisible = true;
            await LongMethod();
        }`. However the loading message still doesn't show up until after LongMethod is finished running